# How to use secret key for on-demand revalidation for ISR (Next.js) in the frontend without exposing it?

Tags: next.js

According to [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#using-on-demand-revalidation), you should use a SECRET_TOKEN to prevent unauthorized access to your revalidate API route i.e.

`https://<your-site.com>/api/revalidate?secret=<token>`

But how are you supposed to call that route from the frontend and keep the token secret?

For example, if you have a simple POST that you then want to trigger the revalidate off of, you'd have to expose your secret token via NEXT_PUBLIC to be able to use it:

```
function handleSubmit(payload) {
  axios.post(POST_URL, payload)
  .then(() => {
    axios.get(`/api/revalidate?secret=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_TOKEN}`)
  })
  .then(() => {
    // redirect to on-demand revalidated page
  })
}
```

What am I missing here? How can you call the API route through the frontend without exposing the SECRET_TOKEN?

Comment: the revalidate route is just for you.  You shouldn't be calling that from your font-end.

Comment: @MattTimmermans but I believe a common use case would be if a user edits a page and you want to show them the edited page instantly - you would have to use on-demand revalidation. As per my answer below, Next.js' video walking through on-demand revalidation actually don't use a SECRET_KEY so I guess I just omit it and hope no users abuse the API route?

Comment: If *lots* of users, or *any* user can do things that change the page, then it's not static.  If we're talking about users who are specifically authorized to edit the page, then you can either trust *just them* with the secret, or protect that route with the same authentication + authorization you use to protect the editing feature.

Comment: @MattTimmermans - I mean in my specific use case, say I have users who can make comments. I want to allow a user to edit a comment and update that specific comment via on-demand revalidation. As far as I can tell, there's no way to protect that revalidate route in this specific scenario? Anyone can just `GET` `https://<your-site.com>/api/revalidate?slug=/comment/123` to re-validate `/comment/123` and not just the original commenter.

Comment: That's not a static page. Use getServerSideProps instead of getStaticProps, and you don't have to worry about revalidation at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Next.js video demo don't actually use a SECRET_KEY.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGexHR1tuOA

So I guess I'll just have to omit it and hope nobody abuses the revalidate API?

Comment: Did you manage to find a better solution? I'm facing the same issue here.
The only idea that occurred to me was to have an additional API function that is called by the frontend, and in return, it calls the API route with the secret (since the secret is now available on the next server).

Comment: But then again, anyone can call this intermediary API function, so it's practically the same.

Comment: @Kox - No, I never found a solution unfortunately. Doesn't look like it's possible at this time.

Comment: yea, this seems to be out of scope for Next. However, the docs seem to be redundant for that.
https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-1#on-demand-incremental-static-regeneration-beta

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying out On-Demand ISR and stumbled on a similar problem. I was trying to revalidate data after CRUD actions from my Admin dashboard living on the client, behind protected routes ("/admin/...").

If you have an authentication process setup and you're using Next-Auth's JWT strategy, it gives you access to the [`getToken()`](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#using-gettoken) method, which decrypts the JWT of the current authenticated user.

You can then use whatever information you have passed through your [callbacks](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks) to validate the request instead of relying on a `SECRET_TOKEN`.

```javascript
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

const secret = process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET;

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const user = await getToken({ req, secret });
  if (!user || user.role !== "ADMIN") {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Revalidation not authorized"});
  }

  try {
    // unstable_revalidate is being used in Next 12.1
    // I'm passing the revalidation url through the query params
    await res.unstable_revalidate(req.query.url as string);
    return res.json({ revalidated: true });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send("Error revalidating");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create one file called ".env".

Inside the file, you put the params `.env` like this:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_TOKEN=123password
```

You must install the dependency `dotenv`:

```
npm i dotenv
```

and then you can call inside your function like this

```
function handleSubmit(payload) {
  axios.post(POST_URL, payload)
    .then(() => {
      axios.get(`/api/revalidate?secret=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_TOKEN}`)
    })
    .then(() => {
      // redirect to on-demand revalidated page
    })
}
```

Comment: Whoops, yes, you're right. I forgot to include process.env in my OP. But my question centers around how the documentation says to keep the SECRET_TOKEN secret but I HAVE to expose it via NEXT_PUBLIC_ if I want to use it on my frontend. So how am I supposed to keep a token secret if I want to use it in my frontend?

Comment: Right. The token ain't secret anymore if we are adding it to URLs generated in frontend